# Can someone help me figure out instinctively whats going on here?

Tags: circuit-analysis, dc

V4 is intentionally left disconnected. I understand that this is an open circuit and current cannot flow. What I'm trying to understand is why does Vout = 5V and not 8.2 V. What key assumption am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: Why do you think Vout should be 8.2 Volts?

Comment: Hint, Vout is measured with respect to ground.

Comment: Nothing to do with instincts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no current through \$R_1\$. Therefore there is no voltage drop across it. Therefore, both leads of \$R_1\$ are at the same potential. Therefore, \$V_{OUT}=5\:\textrm{V}\$ since \$V_1\$ sets the voltage on the left side of \$R_1\$. Note that when you measure \$V_{OUT}\$, it is taken with reference to the "0" node (or ground.)

\$V_3\$ "hangs off" of that point. So the (-) end of it will be \$-3.2\:\textrm{V}\$. Etc.

Answer (score 5):

## Intuition

Although you have already accepted your answer, I'll add another one, since you want to "instinctively" be able to solve such problems.

Most times, when there are no extremes involved (i.e., everyday circuits, not HF, no antennae, no air bridging voltages etc.), you can "instinctively" cut off bits that are not connected.

In your example, since V4 is not connected on one leg, cut it off.

Now, V3 is not connected fully. Cut if off.

Now, you end up with a voltage source (U=5V), a resistor of irrelevant size and an open circuit (I=0A) and should, together with I=U/R be able to deduce jonks answer relatively easily.

In fact, I would say that for a beginner who already knows I=U/R and has a vague understanding that electrons are whizzing around in the wires, but not much else, the fact that there is a voltage drop over a resistor (related to the current passing through it) is one of the first things you can try to transform into "intuition". Or, the other way around, intuitively checking voltage drops (in addition/together with) current flows, is a very good way to build up intuition, as the both of them obviously go hand in hand.